# QGIS as a pre and post processor for modflow

Tags: qgis, georeferencing

I want to find out how QGIS can be used as a pre-processor for modflow, i.e delineating the model boundary and boundary conditions etc. exporting to modflow for analysis, viewing and/or mapping the results in QGIS. I am new to QGIS and GIS in general but I was told that this is possible in QGIS.

Comment: Perhaps this post might help: [Use QGIS to create a simple modflow model](http://hydrogeotools.blogspot.co.uk/2014/08/use-qgis-to-create-simple-modflow-model.html)

Comment: Thank you very much for the link. Looks like this can only be done in QGIS via third-party scripting packages.

Comment: Most welcome buddy! Yes, it would seem like you would need third-party modules, this is not something I have done but hopefully others can advise :)

Comment: I am part of a group working to build a MODFLOW / MODPATH / MT3DMS plugin package for QGIS.  Hope to make experimentally available in next couple months, or by start of 2017.  Keep an eye out in their desktop plugin manager!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QSWATMOD is now available. A QGIS plugin for SWAT-MODFLOW.

https://swat.tamu.edu/software/swat-modflow/